# CGContextStrokePath triggers EXC_BAD_ACCESS in iOS > 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4, exc-bad-access, quartz-2d

I have a custom UIButton class that adds a gradient and a gloss effect to the UIButton 
the code works perfectly in iOS 4 and on iOS5 simulator but when i run it on iOS 5 devices it gives me the exception  EXC_BAD_ACCESS , the exception is triggered by the line :

```
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

any help is really appreciated ,
here's my code

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat actualBrightness = _brightness;
    if (self.selected) {
        actualBrightness -= 0.10;
    }   

    CGColorRef blackColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    CGColorRef highlightStart = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.7].CGColor;
    CGColorRef highlightStop = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor;

    CGColorRef outerTop = [UIColor colorWithHue:_hue saturation:_saturation brightness:1.0*actualBrightness alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    CGColorRef outerBottom = [UIColor colorWithHue:_hue saturation:_saturation brightness:0.80*actualBrightness alpha:1.0].CGColor;

    CGFloat outerMargin = 7.5f;
    CGRect outerRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, outerMargin, outerMargin);            
    CGMutablePathRef outerPath = createRoundedRectForRect(outerRect, 6.0);

    // Draw gradient for outer path
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddPath(context, outerPath);
    CGContextClip(context);
    drawLinearGradient(context, outerRect, outerTop, outerBottom);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    if (!self.selected) {

        CGRect highlightRect = CGRectInset(outerRect, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        CGMutablePathRef highlightPath = createRoundedRectForRect(highlightRect, 6.0);

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextAddPath(context, outerPath);
        CGContextAddPath(context, highlightPath);
        CGContextEOClip(context);

        drawLinearGradient(context, CGRectMake(outerRect.origin.x, outerRect.origin.y, outerRect.size.width, outerRect.size.height/3), highlightStart, highlightStop);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        drawCurvedGloss(context, outerRect, 180);
        CFRelease(highlightPath);

    }
    else {
        //reverse non-curved gradient when pressed
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextAddPath(context, outerPath);
        CGContextClip(context);
        drawLinearGloss(context, outerRect, TRUE);      
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    }
    if (!_toggled) {
        //bottom highlight
        CGRect highlightRect2 = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 6.5f, 6.5f);
        CGMutablePathRef highlightPath2 = createRoundedRectForRect(highlightRect2, 6.0);

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.5);
        CGContextAddPath(context, highlightPath2);
        CGContextAddPath(context, outerPath);
        CGContextEOClip(context);
        drawLinearGradient(context, CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.size.height-self.bounds.size.height/3, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height/3), highlightStop, highlightStart);

        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        CFRelease(highlightPath2);
    }
    else {
        //toggle marker
        CGRect toggleRect= CGRectInset(self.bounds, 5.0f, 5.0f);
        CGMutablePathRef togglePath= createRoundedRectForRect(toggleRect, 8.0);

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.5);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
        CGContextAddPath(context, togglePath);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        CFRelease(togglePath);
    }
    // Stroke outer path
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.5);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, blackColor);
    CGContextAddPath(context, outerPath);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CFRelease(outerPath);

}
```

what I really wanna now is that is it really related to iOS 5 or am i doing something else wrong ?

Comment: This is a relatively long method to debug, especially without access to custom functions you have.  Set some break points and try to figure out where in this method it is breaking.  I would guess that one of you Ref's are not what you think they are.

Comment: well the exception is raised at  CGContextStrokePath(Context) which is a part of SDK , what confuses me is that this code works perfectly on iOS 4 and even on the iOS 5 simulator it just doesn't work on any iOS 5 devices

Comment: You also have branching (if-else-statements) in that code. Which of the `CGContextStrokePath()` is crashing for you?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist it doesn't matter actually which branch is executed, the code crashes when evert the methods "CGContextStrokePath(context)" is executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crash happens because the UIColors are already deallocated when you access the CGColorRefs.

An easy way to avoid this is to use

```
UIColor* blackColor = [UIColor blackColor];
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [blackColor CGColor]);
```

instead of

```
CGColorRef* blackColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, blackColor);
```

so ARC doesn't get the chance to deallocate the UIColor objects early.

Comment: I've been working on a very tricky crash for weeks, and I think this answer may have solved it. Thank you!